# ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape. Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (48000,) and arg 1 with shape (2,)

Tags: python

I tried to animate a simple (sine)^3 fucntion using PillowWriter, but stuck with this error.
Belowmentioned is my code for the same:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

def y(x):
    z = 3 * np.sin(x)**3
    return z

fig = plt.figure()
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'g-')

plt.xlim(-12,12)
plt.ylim(-12,12)

metadata = dict(title="3[sin(x)]^3", artist="Me")
writer = PillowWriter(fps=20, metadata=metadata)

x_axis = np.arange(-12, 12, 0.0005)
y_axis = []

with writer.saving(fig, "y(x).gif", 100):
    for x in x_axis:
        y_axis.append(y(x))

        l.set_data(x_axis, y_axis)
        writer.grab_frame()
```

Comment: What expected output would you like? The error is due to the `y_axis` array. You are trying to plot 48000 points on the x axis against two on the y axis? Maybe the values you have set as `y_axis` were supposed to represent something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your `y_axis` is not long enough, so the plot does not know how to compare it to the `x_axis` array. I would suggest the following solution:

```py
from matplotlib.axis import XAxis
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

def y(x):
    z = 3 * np.sin(x)**3
    return z

fig = plt.figure()
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'g-')

plt.xlim(-12,12)
plt.ylim(-12,12)

metadata = dict(title="3[sin(x)]^3", artist="Me")
writer = PillowWriter(fps=20, metadata=metadata)

x_axis = np.arange(-12, 12, 0.05) # 0.0005 causes performance issues
y_axis = np.zeros(len(x_axis))

with writer.saving(fig, "y(x).gif", 100):
    for n, x_val in enumerate(x_axis):
        y_axis[n] = y(x_val)
        l.set_data(x_axis, y_axis)
        writer.grab_frame()
```

Explanation: It creates a `y_axis` array which is of equal length as the `x_axis` array, but is filled with zeros. Then, for each frame, it counts and sets the next value of the `y_axis` array equal to the function value. Note: I reduced the resolution of the `x_axis` array because it was giving me performance issues.

Comment: Ah, I understand. I'm new at programming, so that's why I didn't anticipate it. Thanks, though :)

Comment: You're welcome! If the code above works feel free to mark it as the answer so the thread can be closed :)